# Cannot Find Symbol for another class file

Tags: file, class, find, symbols

I've had this problem a few times, where I've created another class file and the main class file can't find it. 
Here's the main class file:

```
package textfiles;

import java.io.IOException;
 public class FileData
 {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String file_name = "Lines.txt";

    try {
        ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
        String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();

        for(int i =0; i<aryLines.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(aryLines);
        }
    }

    catch(IOException e)
    {   
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
  }
```

Here is the class file it can't find:

```
package textfiles;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

 public class ReadFile
 {
private String path;
int numberOfLines=0;

public ReadFile(String file_path)
{
    path = file_path;
}

public String[] OpenFile() throws IOException
{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    int numberOfLines = readLines();
    String[] textData = new String[numberOfLines];

    for(int i=0; i<numberOfLines; i++)
    {
        textData[i] = br.readLine();
    }

    br.close();
    return textData;
}

int readLines() throws IOException
{
    FileReader file_to_read = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(file_to_read);

    String aLine;

    while((aLine = bf.readLine()) != null)
    {
        numberOfLines++;
    }

    bf.close();
    return numberOfLines;
}
  }
```

I've tried running javac textfiles\ReadFile.java and javac textfiles\FileData.java as a suggestion for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903330/cannot-find-symbol-compile-error). That doesn't work. I've made sure I have compiled ReadFile and fixed all the errors there. 
The compiler error I get is:

```
C:\Users\Liloka\Source>javac FileData.java
FileData.java:13: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ReadFile
location: class textfiles.FileData
                    ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
                    ^
  FileData.java:13: cannot find symbol
  symbol  : class ReadFile
  location: class textfiles.FileData
                    ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
                                        ^
  2 errors
```

I'm using notepad++and .cmd so it can't be an IDE error. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure the java files are all in the `textfiles` directory:

```
textfiles/FileData.java
textfiles/ReadFile.java
```

And run:

```
javac textfiles/FileData.java textfiles/ReadFile.java 
java textfiles.FileData
```

Your code works without any modification. I think you are compiling from a wrong directory:

> C:\Users\Liloka\Source>javac FileData.java

Move the `FileData.java` to the `textfiles` directory.

Comment: Thank you! That does make it run but for some reason I'm getting
"[Ljava.lang.String;@19821f" rather than "One" when it's being printed. Do you know why this is? :S 
Thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome. Change `System.out.println(aryLines)` to `System.out.println(aryLines[i])`. [More info about Array's toString()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060016/why-does-tostring-method-in-java-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Comment: Thank you.. I can't believe I missed that off in the first place!

Answer (score 7):

You have to compile all the java files used by your main class. As ReadFile is used by FileData you have to compile it too.

Did you tried

```
javac Filedata.java ReadFile.java
```

or

```
javac *.java
```

?

Comment: " I've made sure I have compiled ReadFile and fixed all the errors there. The compiler error I get is:"
Yes I did :) It was due to location rather than a coding error. But thank you!

Comment: @liloka I meant at the same time. Not separately. Anyway I suppose that you did it.

Comment: Ah, I ended up doing that anyway. Didn't even know you could compile at the same time. So thanks for that :)

Comment: You're welcome @liloka. That is the correct way to compile java programs. Good luck with your project ;)

Comment: @DavidMorenoGarcía do you know why javac needs both files specified at the same time? For example I tried `javac file1.java` and `javac file2.java` and it gave the error, but `javac file1.java file2.java` works.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a conflict with generated classes.
Just try to remove all the classes that have been generated and build project again.